# How to expand parameter pack for dependent types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, class-template

What is the syntax for expanding a parameter pack where the types I want are dependent on the types directly in the pack?

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
   typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename ... T>
struct aggregate_of_foo
{
   typedef std::tuple<foo<T>::value_type...> tuple; // MSVC compiler error here
};
```

Comment: Don't you want `typedef std::tuple<typename foo<T>::value_type...> tuple;`

Comment: Unrelated: can't be just `using tuples =  std::tuple<T...>;`?? Do not understand why you need the `value_type` of `foo`:

Comment: @JeJo In this contrived example, yes. but my actual code is more complicated and doesn't follow the pattern that `foo<T>::value_type` will be the same as `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the keyword `typename` because `value_type` is a dependent name in this context.

```
template <typename ... T>
struct aggregate_of_foo
{
    typedef std::tuple<typename foo<T>::value_type...> tuple; //here
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you meant `foo` instead of `bar` in your `typedef`, you are just missing the `typename` keyword before:

```
template <typename ... T>
struct aggregate_of_foo
{
   using tuple_foo =  std::tuple<typename foo<T>::value_type...>;
                      //         ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Also note that I named it as `tuple_foo` because which makes more sense than having just `tuple`.